# Is it possible to update an ongoing notification after the android app was closed?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have this Android application with an ongoing notification and there I have a copied text from the user's clipboard. So, what I'd like to do is: Whenever the user copies a new text (when he's NOT in my app), update this text on the notification at the Status Bar.

I've looked at the `ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener`, so apparently it's possible to detect when it changes, but how can I do it when the user already exited my app?

Is it possible? Where should I implement this?

For now, I've called the mentioned listener on the `onPause()`, and `onDestroy()` methods, and also called set `moveTaskToBack(true);` when the user press the back button, so it doesn't close the activity, just minimize it.

It works for awhile, but after some time it eventually stops working (when the system eventually stops the activity). Is there a workaround?

Thanks for any help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else had the same issue, take a look at `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

Solved my problem. Did exactly what I wanted to do.